# React Navigation (V2): How to prevent (lock) the drawer from opening within a nested stack?

Tags: react-native, locking, react-navigation, drawer

I'm building an app using React Native and I use React Navigation for my navigation.

In order to be able to have modals and regular card transitions for a stack as well have a burger menu, I have my `HomeStack` nested inside my `MainStack` which is inside my `MainDrawer`.

The code looks like this:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({...});
const MainStack = createStackNavigator({ HomeStack, ... }, { mode: "modal" });
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({ MainStack, ... });
```

The problem is that inside the pages of my `HomeStack` the user is expected to do swipe motions which often lead to accidentally opening the drawer. Therefore I want to lock the drawer for the `HomeStack`, when screens have been pushed onto it.

Here comes the problem: [The docs give this solution](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens), but this does not work in my case, since the stack is nested inside another stack.

```
// What I tried and what (obviously?) won't work
HomeStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = "unlocked";
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    drawerLockMode = "locked-closed";
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};

MainStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = "unlocked";
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    drawerLockMode = "locked-closed";
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};
```

Is there any way to for example know about the child stack's state, so that I could use a similar technique to lock the drawer?

```
// Example pseudo code:
MainStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = "unlocked";
  if (navigation.state.HomeStack.state.index > 0) { // here!
    drawerLockMode = "locked-closed";
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[The same doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens) provides another option(recommended) to rearrange the stacks. It works by having drawer in a main stack along with screens where drawer needs to be locked.

> Another option here would be to add another stack navigator as a parent of the drawer navigator, and put the details screen there. This is recommended.